# How to rank numbers by their numerical value?

Tags: algorithm, math

How can I convert a list of arbitrary numbers to a ranked list?

Take the following numbers for example:

```
1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11
```

Translated to ranked list:

```
rank: value
   1: 1
   2: 2
   3: 3
   3: 3
   4: 6
   5: 8
   5: 8
   5: 8
   6: 9
   7: 10
   7: 10
   8: 11
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Stuff elegance, do it the way you've already done it ... first number has rank 1, read the next number, if it's the same as the previous one give it the same rank if not add 1 to rank, repeat until done.

Comment: Make an int value that only increases when you see a new value

Comment: Well in SQL: http://rextester.com/INT56552 using a dense_rank() analytical function.  But I wasn't sure what language/tools you were attempting this in. `SELECT NO, Dense_rank() over (order by No) as rnk from cte`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11];

let idx = 0;
for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(i>0 && arr[i] == arr[i-1])
        console.log(idx);
    else
        console.log(++idx);
}
```

Just check if the value in array is equal to the previous array. If it is then the rank would remain the same else increase the rank

Comment: Assumes input array is ordered no? (arbitrary numbers in question right?)  (easy enough to fix but there it is)

Comment: The question offers an already-sorted list of numbers as an exemplar, I think @marvel308 is entitled to make an answer starting from that point.